# WebClient to consuming JSON and send their values for properties

Tags: c#, json

I "founded" a really good online tool to create a C# class to me (http://json2csharp.com/), but now I need to create a WebClient that consume the JSON and populate the properties with their respective values.

Actually I already have tried to make my own WebClient, but I don't know how to implement him to the generated code from JSON2Csharp.

The JSON2CSharp code:

```
 public class UserModel 
 {
    public int communityvisibilitystate { get; set; }
    public int profilestate { get; set; }
    public string personaname { get; set; }
    public int lastlogoff { get; set; }
    public string profileurl { get; set; }
    public string avatar { get; set; }
    public string avatarmedium { get; set; }
    public string avatarfull { get; set; }
    public int personastate { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public List<UserModel> users { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I've tried to do this with the UserModel's class:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public UserModel()
    {
        WebClient request = new WebClient();
        var response = request.DownloadString(url);

        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(response, this);
    }

    ...
}
```

But without success (as it was expected). So I ask: what can I do to make my WebClient compatible with the JSON2Csharp's code?

Thanks in advance.

**==== UPDATE ====**

My view:

```
@model DotaMix.Models.UserModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = @Model.personaname;
}
```

The problem: the title is invisible.

**==== UPDATE ====**

My full model's code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using ServiceStack.Text;

namespace Mix.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        public UserModel()
        {
            WebClient request = new WebClient();
            var response = request.DownloadString(url);

            JsonConvert.PopulateObject(response, this);
        }

        public string steamid { get; set; }
        public int communityvisibilitystate { get; set; }
        public int profilestate { get; set; }
        public string personaname { get; set; }
        public int lastlogoff { get; set; }
        public string profileurl { get; set; }
        public string avatar { get; set; }
        public string avatarmedium { get; set; }
        public string avatarfull { get; set; }
        public int personastate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public List<UserModel> users { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Response response { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. What is not working? What error do you get?

Comment: So, he simply doesn't works. Seems haven't communication between WebClient and properties.

Comment: i really didnt get your question. The code that u have given should be working, there is no flaw in it. what do mean by "make my WebClient compatible with the JSON2Csharp code"?

Comment: Look: `JsonConvert.PopulateObject(response, this);` I'm using "response" — is this right?

Comment: You need to pass an instance of what json2sharp called `RootObject` (in you case, `UserModel.RootObject`) to the `JsonConvert.PopulateObject`.

Comment: So... `JsonConvert.PopulateObject(response, new RootObject());`? If yes, this returns me a Stackoverflow Exception.

Comment: json2sharp create the RootObject as the "main" class of the json string. Usually you just need to pass an instance of it to PopulateObject or DeserializeObject. What is the url of the json you are trying to parse, or can you link a sample?

Comment: Try to move the code from the constructor of UserModel to the constructor of RootObject

Comment: The URL what I have trying to parse is [this](http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=B88B7699C6EACAE138DDB93BED6467EC&steamids=76561198026602449). I passed the constructor from UserModel to RootObject, but without success. I have debugged the application with a breakpoint to check the problem and I could see that the program isn't even past the RootObject's class.

Comment: Isn't even passed RootObject's class*

Comment: this works: http://pastebin.com/aQNtjLHs

Comment: Yes! Worked! But... To send the data for the view, any suggestions? (Oh, thank you very much for the attention!)

Comment: see my answer below for a suggestion

Comment: JsonConvert.PopulateObject() + http://json2csharp.com/ = AmAzInG!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, take a look here for the full code on how to do what you want: http://pastebin.com/aQNtjLHs

The JSON you are getting can return more than 1 player. If you are sure that it only returns 1, you can use like this:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    WebClient request = new WebClient();
    var url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?    key=B88B7699C6EACAE138DDB93BED6467EC&steamids=76561198026602449";
    var response = request.DownloadString(url);

    var myObject = new RootObject();

    JsonConvert.PopulateObject(response, myObject);
    //get only the first player     
    return View(myObject.response.players.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

View:

```
@model DotaMix.Models.Player

@Model.personaname
```

Now, if that json really returns more than 1 player, you could do it like this:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    WebClient request = new WebClient();
    var url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=B88B7699C6EACAE138DDB93BED6467EC&steamids=76561198026602449";
    var response = request.DownloadString(url);
    var myObject = new RootObject();
    JsonConvert.PopulateObject(response, myObject);
    return View(myObject.response);
}
```

View:

```
@model DotaMix.Models.Response

@foreach (var player in Model.players)
{
  <li>@player.personaname</li>
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Oh, Leo, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen you are using Newtonsoft assembly. Have you tried to include the JsonProperty definitions?.

```
[JsonProperty("TheProperty")]
```

Check this example class:

```
namespace Json.CareerJsonTypes
{

    internal class Act13
    {

        [JsonProperty("completed")]
        public bool Completed { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("completedQuests")]
        public IList<CompletedQuest9> CompletedQuests { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Carlos. Thank you about your contribution. So, I've tried this: `[JsonProperty("personaname")]
        public string personaname { get; set; }`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. NewtonSoft use that marks to fill the class properties with the json response

Comment: Ok. I did this, but without success. =(

Comment: Have you checked the webresponse contains data?. A valida json format?. Maybe you need some kind of authentication?

Comment: Have data, yes! But the JSON is multidimensional. Look: `{
 "response": {
  "players": [
   {
    "steamid": "76561198026602449"`

Comment: Your response contains the class "players", you have to use the JsonProperty's with that name. I recommend you to change the class name as well. You are using now UserModel dont you?

Comment: Ok, I made the changes. In JsonProperty, I have to use 
`[JsonProperty("players")]` instead of `[JsonProperty("personaname")]`?